# ASP.NET: id attribute is invalid for tags that are not inherited from control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I opened up my project and this error that I do not know what they mean exactly: error comes up on the 'ID' attribute of my update panel. I have searched through google and SO but have found nothing.

> id attribute is invalid for tags that are no inherited from control

I have never seen this before so I am not too sure what has gone wrong as it wasn't throwing this error yesterday nor can I see any syntax errors.

The only clue I have is that it could be something to do with the aspx directive or the master page which the aspx inherits.

This is the block of code that is throwing the error:

```
<div class="form-group">               
        <label  class="col-lg-4 control-label">Course:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateCourse" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourse" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Select Course</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
             </ContentTemplate> 
                <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlFaculty" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                    </Triggers>                                        
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>                  
    </div>               
</div>
```

The page directive incase its something in there:

```
<%@ Page Title=""  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddStudent.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddStudent" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

And the .master which the aspx inherits:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="IT7x11Project.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"it could be something to do with the aspx directive or the master page"_ Why do you think so? Is ajax registered properly, is `asp` the tag that you have assigned for it as `TagPrefix`?

Comment: Are you using source control (please say yes)? Then compare your local version to the last known working version in source control and spot the difference.